# Java - Creating an array from user input

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Here is the assignment:

> 1. Create an array to store 10 numbers.
> 2. Using a loop, prompt the user to enter 10 grades and store them in the array.
> 3. Then make another loop that prints the numbers in the array out backwards and adds up the numbers in the array.
> 4. Use the sum to calculate the average of the numbers.  Print out the average of the numbers.

My code so far:

```
public static void ar() {

    double[] grades = new double[10];
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int i=0; i < grades.length; i++)
        grades[i]=kb.nextDouble();

    double sum=0;

    for(int j=10; j > grades.length; j--)
        sum=sum+grades[j];

    double ave = sum/10;

    System.out.println(ave);
}
```

However it only prints 0.0 ten times.

Comment: Are you trying to write in Javascript?  Or in Java?  Big difference.  Please fix your title if this is Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an annotated solution indicating what was changed from your initial code. You were definitely on the right track, just a few small issues.

```
public static void ar() {

    double[] grades = new double[10];
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int i=0; i < grades.length; i++)
        grades[i]=kb.nextDouble();

    double sum=0;

    for(int j=9; j >= 0; j--) //Note here that we've changed our condition. It was running zero times before. Additionally it now runs from 9-0, since the last index is 9
        sum=sum+grades[j];

    //Look out for Integer Arithmetic!
    double ave = sum/10.0;

    System.out.println(ave);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The bounds in your `for` loop to iterate backwards were wrong.  You mean to use `for (int j=10; j>=0; j--)`.  Try this code:

```
public static void ar() {
    double[] grades = new double[10];
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i=0; i<grades.length; i++)
        grades[i] = kb.nextDouble();

    double sum = 0;

    for (int j=grades.length-1; j>=0; j--)
        sum = sum + grades[j];

    double ave = sum / 10;
    System.out.println(ave);
}
```

Comment: @CollinD Because the variable `sum` is a `double`, it is possible to divide by an `int` and still get a `double` result.

Comment: Good to know! Wasn't quite sure how Java would decide to handle that one.