# getting an input by scanner and creating an array only using for loop not

Tags: java, arrays

```
private static int[] arr;
public static void inputarrays() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("length of an array");

    int x = scan.nextInt();
    arr = new int[x];

    System.out.println("values of an array");
    for(int n = 0; n < x; x++) {
        arr[n] = scan.nextInt();
    }
}
```

I looked up how to write code for getting an user input and creating an array like this one:
 [Java - Creating an array from user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33093553/java-creating-an-array-from-user-input)

It looks like my code is same as on the link's one which means it should work correctly. However, the scanner never closes when I enter the values of an array. I tried `scan.close()`, but it did not work. Also, I cannot use try&exception for this one.

Comment: Change x++ to n++

Comment: I changed it but the scanner still does not stop

Comment: Add this line: `scan.nextLine();` after each `scan.nextInt();`

Comment: and thank you for editing, I would follow the format next time

Comment: it sill does not work should I make a new array inside of the method instead of declaring it in the data field?

Comment: See the code in my answer.

Comment: [Your code works fine if you change the `x++` to `n++`](https://tio.run/##hVHNToQwEL73KSacIESi7k304NFET5zMhkNlu2wRpqQdkI3h2XGw7Eo0Wecyab@/mUwle3lV7d4n3bTGElT8TjrSdfJorTy6VPwBskIiKptObfdW6wKKWjoHL1IjfAoBXK3VvSQFjiQxQSNtc5DWph71sgXsjd5Bw@IwI6ux/GaWLmIvWGoJBMcdHgDVx@krzI6OVJNojFLxw/efpqOEJ0GqMQxqhSUdwOyBPeS8WrCWMAsG9p4jElQDPSGFUXrGWbEkz8sM@T9pvaw75X6nnRR7Y8M5cF7mOuV2DwO3OF4vvaRuMb8w1lxn7FmjWoPj5RlfTWf9bFAYJL6Au4MAYvCHT8j4g4TMiRbbUYximjbiRtyKjfgC).

Answer (score 1):

This method is working, try it:

```
private static int[] arr;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("length of an array");
    int x = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
    arr = new int[x];
    System.out.println("values of an array");
    for(int n=0; n<x; n++){
        arr[n]=scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
    }
}
```

1. changed `x++` to `n++`, because `n` is the index of the loop
2. added `scan.nextLine();` after each call to `scan.nextInt()` so that each input line is fully consumed.

Comment: I had to declare arr in the data field so that is why I put it outside of the method. If I keep in that way, does it gonna keep that error?

Comment: The `nextLine()`s are redundant here.

Comment: The `arr` _is_ declared in the question on the first line.

Comment: @Ivar I thought so, but 1 out of 2 times I run the code without the nextLine(); in InteliJ, the loop does not stop.

Comment: @forpas I know that's the case [if you use `nextLine` after `next` or `nextFoo`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo). Besides that, I personally never had trouble in IntelliJ myself. (But that doesn't mean that others don't of course.)

Comment: @Ivar there is a problem for sure when you mix inputs with nextLine() and nextInt(). In the case where only nextInt() is used I also never had no problems. But it could happen and just to be on the safe side...

Answer (score -2):

You used `n` for your loop so you have to go for `n++` and not `x++`.

```
private static int[] arr;
public static void inputarrays() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("length of an array");

    int x = scan.nextInt();
    arr = new int[x];
    System.out.println("values of an array");
    for(int n = 0; n < x; n++) {
        arr[n] = scan.nextInt();
    }
}
```

It should work this way.

Comment: this answer has nothing that hasn't already been said in other answers.